# Build a xml post request and accept the response using JSR in java

Tags: java, xml, rest, post

I'm trying to build a rest client as well as a server using Post method. I have created a sample client to submit the rest request.

```
    public class TestRequests {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        String request = "http://localhost:8080/TestRest/resources/generic/";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod method = new PostMethod(request);

        method.addParameter("name", "hello");

        // Send POST request
        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        System.out.println("the status code is-----" + statusCode);
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
        }
        InputStream rstream = null;

        // Get the response body
        rstream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();

        // Process the response from Yahoo! Web Services
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rstream));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }

}
```

I have my server side code where I'm trying read the parameter that I have added. But I'm unable to do so.

```
@POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
   public String sayHelloPost(@QueryParam ("name") String name) {
        return "Hello World!" + name;
    }
```

Here I'm not able to get the value that I'm sending from my client.

The same with the GET works fine.

Also I'd like to know how to send a xml instead of the string in my request and get the xml in the response. Can a XML Document be sent directly.

Thanks in advance.

-Garudadwajan

Comment: I think `@QueryParam` is for `GET` requests.

Comment: Thanks for replying asgs. What is the equivalent of@QueryParam for a POST request?

Comment: It's @FormParam. See the examples at [Overview of JAX-RS 1.0 Features](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features)

Comment: @asgs Hi, Yes. I did add '@FormParam' and added '@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)'. It works fine now.

Now I'm able to add a xml as a string. But if I read the xml as a document and send it to the server, it throws an error saying JAXB cannot read from an interface. Is it possible to send a document object or do I have to send it as a string itself?

Comment: You might want to post some code how you're reading the xml, so that we can help.